# React JS .map returns all data the same times as objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, treeview

I'm new to React (2 days) but stuck with the task to view JSON as tree view.
Need to show as collapsed menu nodes labels and on click show their data.

I finally find solution to show nodes labels, but they are shown all in one list item and repeated as much times as much nodes I have.

Here is mys JSON

```
  {
  "main": {
    "nodes": {
      "firstnode": {
        "storage": [
          "1",
          "1",
          "3"
        ],
        "interfaces": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      },
      "secondnode": {},
      "thirdnode": {}
    }
  },
    "secondary": {}
}
```

Here is my code

```
    const LeftTreeNodes = Object.keys(data.left.nodes).map(item =>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li key={Object.keys(data.left.nodes)}>
     {Object.keys(data.left.nodes)}
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `item` that you are mapping to print each one:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    {Object.keys(data.left.nodes).map(item =>
      <li key={item}>
        {item}
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
</div>
```

This will map through the keys on `data.left.nodes` and render an `li` for each one with the value of each one.

Comment: @DavinTyron and what will be the right way to build the tree?